# Should you put a Notification preference into your Inapp preferences (Android)

Tags: mobile, android, push-notification

Our Android app is featuring push-notifications, and we want the user to be able to activate/deavtivate them.
Should we make an option for this in our inapp-preferences or is it just confusing because the user is able to configure this for every app in the android preferences?

Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the users are aware of this setting in your app, it will be difficult to get them to use it. Instead of putting it inside Preferences, if it is really important, it could be separated into its own option to stand out and be easily discoverable.

It is important to ask what advantages does it offer to the users in doing it this way. Does it offer them more flexibility to choose more notification options?

The best way will be to keep things contextual and suggest users to turn on Notification when they try to access features which require Notifications.

Comment: I just have one type of notification and im not giving the user more flexibility by adding a second way to turn them on and off. so i'm removing the option and leave it to the os

Answer (score 0):

While users are able to choose whether or not they want to receive notifications (and in some newer android versions, if they want it to display notifications bubbles on the icon) from your app, they cannot chose what kinds of notifications they want to get. That's a binary all or none decision.

If, for example, you have two kinds of notifications, one when the user gets a message and one when they are added to a group chat, they might be interested in only being notified when they get a message and would appreciate a setting that disables other notifications.

If you have multiple kinds of notifications that might not all be equally important/ interesting, it's always a good idea to let the user chose what they want to see.

Answer (score 0):

You (and/or the business for which you are making apps) are much better off to capture such User customisations as you can:

- aggregate analytics on such usage,
- provide finer granularity than the OS in tailoring the customisation,
- provide additional supporting information to the User,
- temporarily ignore the settings so as to say test whether a User benefits or gets really annoyed from a notification slipping through.